# Encrypt Django Source Code information is still not there yet?

Tags: django

i have search some information about encrypt the django source code like ioncube for php or other.
but for django i can't find the information, there are a few question for many years with negative answer.
its still not there yet the encryptor for django ?

and if its still not there yet, what the solution to protect the source code if we have to put the source code in the local client server.

if you have the solution please to tell me how to or what you usually do to protect your source code if you have to put this in your client server, where your client can access and see it too.

thanks before,

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Cython, which translates your Python code into C, then you can ship binaries. But this requires adaption and knowledge of both languages.

In reality, you can't **encrypt** Python code, everything can be reverse engineered if someone puts effort.

You should handle this through legal licenses and lawyers.